# Problem with PopupMenu: Its values don't update dynamically

Tags: programming, dynamic, evaluation, gui-construction, initialization

I have a problem with `PopupMenu` inside `DynamicModule`, its values don't update dynamically as they supposed to. The example below demonstrates the issue.

```
DynamicModule[{inputData = 0, dataSet1 = {0}, popupSelection, value1, value2 }, 
 Dynamic@Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[inputData]], 
    Button["Plot", dataSet1 = Table[inputData + i^j, {i, 5}, {j, 2}]],
     Spacer[5],
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[popupSelection], {value1 -> "v1", value2 -> "v2"}],
    ListPlot[popupSelection, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300}, 
     Frame -> True]}],
 Initialization :> (
   value1 = dataSet1;
   value2 = dataSet1 + 1;
   ), 
 SynchronousInitialization -> False]
```

The `PopupMenu` is linked to `ListPlot`, for example: if `value1` with label "v1" is selected from the list then ListPlot should print the evaluated value of `value1` and the same goes for `value2`.

The problem I have is that `value1` and `value2` which correspond to `popupSelection` don't update dynamically when changing the input of `InputField` and pressing button "Plot". These values evaluate only once (upon `DynamicModule` evaluation) using initial values and they do not re-evaluate when required. I tried to wrap expressions of `value1` and `value2` with `Dynamic` but it conflicts with `ListPlot` giving me bunch of error messages.

I know i'm missing something here, I just can't figure out what it is. Please help!

cross-posted on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1629011?p_p_auth=vnhZw1yV)

**Edit:**

The question has been answered on **[Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1629011?p_p_auth=vnhZw1yV)**

Comment: Kamila, perhaps you could summarize the solution proposed by Wolfram Community in an answer of yours here, so the question will show up as answered for future users. Links may easily break in the future and the solution may be overlooked.

Comment: You initialize `value1` and `value2` but you never update them in `DynamicModule`. You update `dataSet1` but that is not linked to `value1` and `value2`.  You could get it mostly working by swaping `Set` for `SetDelayed` in the `Initialization` option.